# Secure method to download files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, security

A common way to download files in Ruby is using the `open-uri` library and simply calling `open(url)`. However, it has been [pointed](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/2xgypm/using_rubys_openuri_one_step_away_from_rce/) [out](https://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html) that this passes input along to `Kernel#open`, which is not safe to call with untrusted input (starting with a pipe spawns a subprocess, etc).

What is the best practice way to securely download a file in Ruby when the URL is constructed from potentially untrusted user input?

Comment: Define "securely". What is your threat model? Who is your attacker? How much money and resources does he have? Also, what are you protecting? How much money is it worth? How much money and resources do you have?

Comment: Securely meaning the URL (potentially containing untrusted input) is either downloaded or fails, but nothing malicious happens other than that (like retrieving files on the filesystem or spawning other processes as `Kernel#open` can do). Just a standard question about best practices when retrieving files under normal circumstances, nothing more extreme than that.

Comment: I am assuming by "download files" you are referring to downloading from the internet using standard HTTP, HTTPS and FTP type protocols. If so why not use the libraries designed for doing so `Net::HTTP`, `Net::HTTPS`, and `Net::FTP`?

Comment: @engineersmnky The examples I've seen (as well as the top answers to another couple Stack Overflow questions) use `open-uri`, but maybe that's the answer (using the underlying libraries directly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, consider why are you allowing this in the first place? Giving users the power to open *arbitrary URLs* **on the server** is an unusual (and "dangerous") thing to be doing in the first place!

For instance, even if you were to protect against process spawns, the user could still open arbitrary code from the internet - e.g. a virus.

It is most likely that any system allowing this will *already trust* its users. For example, perhaps the only user is yourself!!

...With that said, [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/25b104ce98821115f2b5e0a3b5b9ac131384b233/lib/open-uri.rb#L13-L41) is the source code for `Kernel#open` *when you have also used `require 'open-uri'`*:

```
alias open_uri_original_open open

def open(name, *rest, &block)
  if name.respond_to?(:open)
    name.open(*rest, &block)
  elsif name.respond_to?(:to_str) &&
        %r{\A[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-\.]*://} =~ name &&
        (uri = URI.parse(name)).respond_to?(:open)
    uri.open(*rest, &block)
  else
    open_uri_original_open(name, *rest, &block)
  end
end
```

So for the use case of *only* opening a URL, you can see that the implementation is to call: `URI.parse(url).open`. Therefore, your "secure" code could be implemented as:

```
def open_url(url)
  if url =~ URI.regexp
    URI.parse(url).open
  else
    # Handle this somehow?
  end
end
```

...But remember, as I said above, you really need to think twice before downloading arbitrary URLs! You should probably only being doing this if you *already trust the user input*; in which case my above code is likely unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested in this post: https://twin.github.io/improving-open-uri/

**Kernel#open**

Ruby has a `Kernel#open` method, which given a file path acts as `File.open`. but given a string that starts with “|”, it interprets it as a shell command and returns an IO connected to the spawned subprocess:

```
open("| ls") # returns an IO connected to the `ls` shell command
```

Open-uri extends `Kernel#open` with the ability to accept URLs. However, if the URL is coming from user input, we should never pass it to `Kernel#open`, because different users have different ideas on what is a “URL”; someone might think that `| rm -rf ~` is a nice looking URL.

A little known fact is that `Kernel#open` just delegates to `URI::(HTTP|HTTPS|FTP)#open`, and we can simply use that instead:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/image.jpg") #=> #<URI::HTTP>
uri.open #=> #<Tempfile:/var/folders/k7/6zx6dx6x7ys3rv3srh0nyfj00000gn/T/20160524-10403-xpdakz>
```

Comment: And to get the actuall content of the file you should call *.read* like:
`URI.parse(<url_here>).read`